# HTML dropdownlists in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can get this to work.

```
<div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TopicDescription,
new SelectList(ViewBag.TopicDescription, "TopicDescription", "TopicDescription"))
</div>
```

BUT my code doesn't look clean as in the Topic class I have a field called TopicDescription. I wanted to tidy it up so I changed that class field to be called Description.

```
<div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TopicDescription,
new SelectList(ViewBag.Description, "Description", "Description"))
</div>
```

However now my selection drop down list is not correctly populated on load. My questions is concerning this. Does anyone know if there is a connection between the names in the drop down list and the names in the selection. Somehow is MVC linking the two.

Comment: can u post your controller code

Answer (score 0):

If you see the `SelectList` [constructor definition here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286.aspx) , the first one is the object (`IEnumerable`), and the second and third are `dataValueField` and `dataTextField` respectively. so these values must be matched to the name of properties  of object contained in the first parameter

Comment: okay I see. Do you know if there is any way that I could make it work with a different name? I really think it's strange to have things like a class called Topic and then a field in that class called TopicDescription. Thanks for ur advice so far.